# Multiple execution of Selenium without using Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run my Selenium execution using multiple browsers.
But I don't want to use Selenium Grid. I have tried with Java multithreading, but it's getting difficult to handle all the threads.
Can anyone help me with an easier way, other than Selenium Grid?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use Selenium Grid? If so, you should probably edit it into your post.

Comment: i dont have multiple systems, i and want simualtaneous execution

Comment: @AutoMater do you want sequential execution or parallel?

Comment: Try to use some CI tool like jenkins where you can achieve this.

Comment: i acheived it using multithreading by Java.

Answer (score 0):

For easier way to run tests in parallel and multi-thread you can try TestNG framework. I hope that well suites for your requirement. You can get more details [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests)

Answer (score 0):

If your box is capable of handling multiple programming instance, then you can user JUNIT and kick multiple test from eclipse.

You can also look over saucelabs.com